# Creating SQL views dynamically using Java

Tags: java, sql

So I was wonderning if there is a way to create SQL views dynamically using Java. Here is what I meant with dynamic views.
Normally to create a view we simply use the code below:
Create view view_name as
Select col1, col2 from table1
Union 
Select col3, col4, col5 from table3
...

but what if view_name, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, table1 and table3 are all variables? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by **views** in the context you're using it. For an SQL query, I should think a view would be a means to see the data (a resultSet) related to the query fired against the database, perhaps through a JTable which can be modified from one query to another. Any variables can be used to make up the SQL String as long as they are handled properly and those variables hold valid names to valid database fields and the values are of proper data type. Remember, it is a SQL Query **String**. Perhaps show a code example of what you mean.

Comment: I'm developing an app with two relational databases. The first database stores data about the employees of an organization X in the state A and the second database stores data about the employees of the same organization X in the state B. So I created SQL views over the tables of the two databases in order for the end users to display data later. But the problem is that the organization is planning to add more databases later (the number of DBs to add isn't fixed). The reason why I wanted to create views dynamically but I have no idea how can I do that?